# batchwise values consumption using python list and dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures, fifo

Hello all i need a little help in finding solution for a datastructure problem using python .
I have two datastructures, batches dictionary which contain batch qty for a certain batch and second datastucture so_data is list of orders. Now task is to loop over so_data and consume batchwise quantities in batches on FIFO basis.

```
batches = {'batch1': 200, 'batch2': 300, 'batch3': 200, 'batch4': 200,
         'batch5': 400, 'batch6': 100, 'batch7': 200, 'batch8': 300}

so_data = [50, 50, 50, 10, 340, 10, 40, 20, 150, 330, 50, 150, 20, 50, 30, 100, 60]


def batchwise_consumption(so_data, batches):
    print(batches)
    for so_qty in so_data:

        for bch,bch_qty in batches.items():
            if bch_qty > 0:
                print('order qty: ', so_qty, ', curr batch qty: ', bch_qty, ', curr batch: ', bch)
                if bch_qty >= so_qty:
                    # order fullfilled by one batch
                    batches[bch] = bch_qty - so_qty
                    print('\trem qty: ', batches[bch])
                    break # break on full filling order
                else:
                    # order fullfilled by partial batches
                    partial_qty = batches[bch]
                    batches[bch] = batches[bch] - batches[bch]
                    rem_so_qty = so_qty-partial_qty
                    print('\tpartial qty', partial_qty, ', rem so qty', rem_so_qty)
                    while partial_qty != so_qty:
                        # make so_qty from multiple batches 
                        break # break on full filling order

    print(batches)
batchwise_consumption(so_data, batches)
```

This problem is part of dataset, following is simulation of batchwise consumption
[image: batchwise consumption]

Any help or some better solution is appreciated.
Thanks in advance for helping .

Comment: I don't know if you can use nested for loops here, because sometimes you want to advance the order, and sometimes you want to advance the batch. You might want them both to be generators, so you can use next on whichever one is expended.  Or just keep indexes ... same thing. You need to be able to advance one or the other, as needed by the algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved:
Well the task was to consume batchwise stock for Sales order list. So after looping sales order I checked: 
If so_qty is less than batch qty and fit within given index of batch qty then decreased so_qty from batch qty, then appended current batch into consumed batch list of dictionary which is maintaining batchwise consumption for each order and finally set current so_qty to 0 as order is fullfilled  
Else if so_qty is greater than batch qty than reduce batch qty from current so_qty, append remaining batch qty to consumed batch list, set current batch to 0 and continue with same so_qty unless it became 0 and break the loop for current so_qty when 0.

```
batches = {'batch1': 200, 'batch2': 300, 'batch3': 200, 'batch4': 200,
         'batch5': 400, 'batch6': 100, 'batch7': 200, 'batch8': 300, 'batch9': 50}

so_data = [50, 50, 50, 10, 340, 10, 40, 20, 150, 330, 50, 150, 20, 50, 30, 100, 60, 400]

def batchwise_consumption(so_data, batches):
    order_no=0
    for so_qty in so_data:
        order_no +=1
        print(order_no, '\tso qty ', so_qty)
        baches_consumed = []
        for bch,bch_qty in batches.items():
            if bch_qty > 0:
                if so_qty <= bch_qty:
                    batches[bch] = bch_qty - so_qty
                    baches_consumed.append({bch: so_qty})
                    so_qty = 0

                elif so_qty > bch_qty:
                    so_qty = so_qty - bch_qty
                    batches[bch] = 0
                    baches_consumed.append({bch: bch_qty})
                    continue

                if so_qty == 0:
                    break
        print('\t', baches_consumed)

batchwise_consumption(so_data, batches)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).